# How to convert (F⇒(H⇒G))⇒(F⇒(G⇒H)) to Conjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I've expanded the formula to:

$$(F \wedge H \wedge\neg G) \vee (\neg F \vee\neg G \vee H)$$

but don't know how to switch the first set to or and the middle or to an and.

Answer (score 2):

Use the distributive law: $(A \wedge B) \vee C = (A \vee C) \wedge (A \vee C)$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed distributive law is one approach, another method is use Absorption law:

\begin{align}
&(F∧H∧¬G)∨(¬F∨¬G∨H)\\
\equiv&(((F∧¬G)∧H)∨H)∨(¬F∨¬G)\tag*{Reordering}\\
\equiv&H∨(¬F∨¬G)\tag*{Absorption law}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\phantom{\equiv}(F\implies(H\implies G))\implies(F\implies(G\implies H))\\
&\equiv\neg(\neg F\lor(\neg H\lor G))\lor(\neg F\lor(\neg G\lor H))\\
&\equiv\neg(\neg F\lor \neg H\lor G)\lor(\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\\
&\equiv(F\land H\land \neg G)\lor(\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\\
&\equiv(F\lor (\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H))\land
(H\lor (\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H))\land
(\neg G\lor (\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H))\\
&\equiv(F\lor \neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\land
(H\lor \neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\land
(\neg G\lor \neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\\
&\equiv 1\land
(\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\land
(\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H)\\
&\equiv\neg F\lor \neg G\lor H
\end{align}